# I need to find a simple interface that can collect a user's contact information centrally

Tags: social-networking

I need to find a simple interface that can collect a user's contact information centrally.  For example, I want to collect one user's contact information (all the contacts in his/her profile) from Facebook,Linkedin and Twitter.

Does springsource provide such capability?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social):

> Spring Social is an extension of the Spring Framework that allows you to connect your applications with Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) providers such as Facebook and Twitter.

It's not a complete application, it's just an API, but it does the hard work for you. It's also quite new, so go easy on it.